# Create a list of values from two list of objects with key value

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class as below..

```
public class MyObject
    {
        public DateTime timeStamp { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
    }
```

I have two lists as below with same timestamp but diff values..
I have tried to show with --> how the data internally is.

```
IReadOnlyList<MyObject> objlistA --> [{1234,56},{1235,78}....]
IReadOnlyList<MyObject> objlistB --> [{1234,98},{1235,32}....]
```

I wish to create a `List<List<int>>` where the values from both objects with same timestamp form the inner list.

Such that my list looks as below..

```
[[56,98],[78,32]......]
```

I'm aware that in my last couple of questions, I was unable to convey my problem statement properly. Please do ask to clarify if you have any queries..

Thanks

Comment: See duplicate. Simply use `ToList()` on each group instead of the `Aggregate()` operation seen there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var groupedByTimestamp = objlistA.Concat(objlistB)
    .GroupBy(o => o.timeStamp)
    .Select(g => g.Select(s => s.value).ToList())
    .ToList();
```